# Do I need to free dynamically created forms?

Tags: delphi, memory-management

If I dynamically create a TForm using TForm.CreateNew(Application) to make a free-floating window do I have to keep track of these objects and free them upon Application close?

Or will delphi automatically free all forms on Application close?

Also, what happens if I have a free-floating dynamically created form and the user hits the close button? Do I need to call some code somewhere to free those?
If so, how? I assume I can't place it in any of the form's events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to free dynamically created forms?

No you don't, except if you create the form with `TForm.CreateNew(nil)`, that is passing no owner to the constructor.

The parameter for `CreateNew` is the owner, if the owner (Application/Form/WhatEverYouLike) gets deleted all owned objects will be freed. Give it a try.

```
procedure TMainfom.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 a:TForm;
begin
 With Tform.CreateNew(Application) do
   begin
   OnClose := MyAllFormClose;
   OnDestroy := AllMyFormDestroy;
   Show;
   end;
end;

procedure TMainfom.AllMyFormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Showmessage(':( I''m going to be destroyed')
end;

procedure TMainfom.MyAllFormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  // unremark if you want to get the form freed OnClose already 
  // Action := caFree;    
end;
```

Comment: A better way is to have a base form for all dynamically created forms and override the `TForm.DoClose` method and set `Action := caFree; inherited;` to have that as the default option. Now it is safe to use the `OnClose` event as usual without side effects

Answer (score 5):

Just to touch on an important point not covered in the other answers...

Yes, when you create a form (or any other component) with an owner, it will be destroyed when the owner is destroyed.
**But, very NB:** *This does not mean you won't have a leak*.  To clarify:

- If every time you create a form you set `Application` as the owner, then the forms will be destroyed by the `Application` object when your app closes.
- But (unless you code something extra), those forms will be destroyed **only** when the application closes.
- In other words, if every time your user selects a particular menu item you create a particular form owned by the application, then more memory will be consumed over time. Depending how much memory is used each time you create the form, your application may run out of memory.

So, provided you don't keep re-creating the objects, the model is perfectly acceptable. However, this means that you do want to keep track of these objects. But not so you can free them yourself, rather so you can re-`Show` them instead of re-creating them.

---

Also to cover some of the other points in your question:

> What happens if I have a free-floating dynamically created form window and the user hits the close button? Will do I need to call some code somewhere to free those?

You don't need to free them if next time your user shows the form you reuse the existing instance. If you're going to create a new instance, then you should free the form when it's closed. Otherwise all the old instances only get destroyed when your application closes.

> How? I assume I can't place it in any of the form's events.

It just so happens that Delphi provides an ideal event: `OnClose`. If you hook that event, then you can set the `var Action: TCloseAction` to indicate what should happen when the form closes. By default:

- An MDI form will be minimised (`caMinimize`).
- And an SDI form will be hidden (`caHide`).

You can change this to destroy the form (`caFree`).

**NOTE**: If you do decide to destroy the form, be careful to not try reusing it after it has been destroyed. Any variable you had that pointed to the form will be pointing to the same location in memory, but the form is no longer there.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter you passed to `CreateNew` is the owner of the component. When a component's owner is destroyed, it destroys all the components that it owns. So, the application object is the owner of your form. When the application closes, the application object is destroyed. And so it destroys all of its owned components. Including your dynamically created form.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it is that people seem to think forms are some kind of magical entity that have their own unique behavior and rules.

Forms are regular objects derived from TForm and TCustomForm, which are ultimately derived from TObject, just like every other class in Delphi.

If you create anything derived from TObject dynamically, it gets destroyed when the application terminates. However, if you fail to destroy it yourself and leave it to the system, that's generally regarded as a "memory leak". It's not a big deal for programs that run once and terminate quickly. But for things that users will leave open for hours or days on end, memory leaks can become quite an annoyance.

As mentioned earlier, TForms have an OnClose event that has a parameter Action. You can set Action to caFree and the form will be destroyed upon return to the Show or ShowModal call that displayed it. But if you use it, you'll need to create the form object yourself rather than use the default auto-create mechanism.

Other types of objects don't have this, like TStringList. You just need to practice "safe object management" and ensure that objects that get created also get destroyed in a timely manner, including forms. This can get into a whole rat's nest of a discussion about stuff related to garbage collection, Interfaces, and a whole lot of related stuff. Suffice it to say, you need to be aware of the options and manage your object lifetimes appropriately, rather than just leaving them to get destroyed when the application terminates.

Comment: thanks for the refresher... I was very good at Delphi back in the day when it was popular. But new to using it again (I needed to make a small tool), so I've forgotten some basic things like that.

Comment: +!.  Maybe worth expanding your final para to mention that interfaces, etc, fall into a different category than TObject descendants, in that the compiler generates code to actively "manage" their lifetimes?  For the benefit of future readers ...

Comment: That's what I meant by the last two sentences. It's enough material for an entire chapter in a book!